# Facebook Error (7) iOS 6

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6

I get this error:

> Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The Facebook server could not
>   fulfill this access request: The proxied app is not already
>   installed." UserInfo=0x114a7440 {NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook
>   server could not fulfill this access request: The proxied app is not
>   already installed.}

I'm using this code to get access:

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                       @"MY APP ID", ACFacebookAppIdKey,
                                                                       nil, ACFacebookPermissionsKey,
                                                                       nil] completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

    if (granted == YES) {

        //My code

    } else {
        NSLog(@"No Facebook access: %@", error.debugDescription);
    }
}];
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you configure your app properly in facebook's settings? sounds like the error message is saying that the (iOS) app isn't installed on the handset that's trying to authenticate the (Facebook) app with iOS

Comment: It works last weekend and I have try to create a new Facebook app and it did not work :(

Comment: My app do not appear in the settings app, but I get a alertView for permission?

Comment: So where is the answer ?

Comment: edit bundle identifier in facebook app

Comment: the sheer number of up-votes on this question clearly suggests it is not a localized problem; for those who find this later, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686277/ios-6-facebook-sharing-procedure-fails-with-error-the-proxied-app-is-not-alre