# iOS 6 - Facebook sharing procedure fails with error "The proxied app is not already installed"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios6

Though, there is such a question [Facebook Error (7) iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498972/facebook-error-7-ios-6) it's already closed without any answer!
While obtaining an access to user's facebook account I've got an error:
`error is: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: The proxied app is not already installed." UserInfo=0xa260270 {NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: The proxied app is not already installed.}`

I'm performing a request like this:

```
self.statusLabel.text = @"Waiting for authorization...";
if (self.accountStore == nil) {
    self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
}   
ACAccountType * facebookAccountType = [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

NSDictionary * dict = @{ACFacebookAppIdKey : FB_APP_ID, ACFacebookAudienceKey : ACFacebookAudienceEveryone};
[self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:dict completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    __block NSString * statusText = nil;
    if (granted) {
        statusText = @"Logged in";
        NSArray * accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];
        self.facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
        NSLog(@"account is: %@", self.facebookAccount);
        self.statusLabel.text = statusText;
        [self postToFeed];
    }
    else {
        self.statusLabel.text = @"Login failed";
        NSLog(@"error is: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

What does this error means?

Comment: can u plz tell self.facebookAccount is of which type.. How i have to declare  @Stas

Comment: Sure, `facebookAccount` is of type `ACAccount` you declare it like this:


`@property (strong, nonatomic) ACAccount * facebookAccount;`

Comment: ok Thank u . Now i am getting this error   The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: The proxied app cannot request publish permissions without having being installed previously.  @Stas

Comment: take a look at this q-a, here's complete guide about how to tune your fb app http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12644229/ios-6-facebook-posting-procedure-ends-up-with-remote-app-id-does-not-match-stor

Comment: Check out my response to the post with similar problem - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686277/ios-6-facebook-sharing-procedure-fails-with-error-the-proxied-app-is-not-alre/19027545#19027545

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've solved this problem!
It was because I do not pass permissions array!
Though the `ACAccountStore` class states that this parameter is optional, it is not!
[image]

More over the application could launch and ask for basic permissions(as it is implied)!

[image]

So, you must always pass a permissions array.

Here's also a description of error codes returned by account store:

```
typedef enum ACErrorCode {
   ACErrorUnknown = 1,
   ACErrorAccountMissingRequiredProperty,
   ACErrorAccountAuthenticationFailed,
   ACErrorAccountTypeInvalid,
   ACErrorAccountAlreadyExists,
   ACErrorAccountNotFound,
   ACErrorPermissionDenied,
   ACErrorAccessInfoInvalid
} ACErrorCode;
```

(I've got `ACErrorPermissionDenied` here)

Comment: It's only when the user first connects to your app (from Facebook's point of view - not the device) that this becomes a problem. Please see my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12851955/662605

Answer (score 11):

We had the same problem and after taking a closer look at the iOS facebook documentation ad

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/

I noticed the following paragraph:

> Note, to use iOS 6 native auth, apps need change the way they request permissions from users - apps must separate their requests for read and write permissions.

I must have read over that one several time but it contained the solution:

You have to do multiple request for access if you want to grant write (publish access). So now we first ask for permission 'email' to get read permission and then for 'publish_action' to be able to post to the timeline.

Comment: yeah, typically basic permissions you get at app start and then obtain advanced when user actually try to use share procedure

Comment: thnx ... it helped me :) +1

Answer (score 8):

The error message is not clear since "app" could be your iOS app? Facebook.app on the phone? Facebook app? The "proxied app" is the Facebook app, and "not already installed" means, it's not yet been associated with the Facebook user online in terms of permissions.

The first time your Facebook app connects to the users Facebook account, you must specify the basic info value(s) in your `ACFacebookPermissionsKey` key of the options dictionary. Other Facebook SDK's past and present such as the Javascript or PHP libraries by default supply basic info as the key, so you never had to. It seems the native integration in iOS doesn't do this, thus, if when the user first connects your app to their Facebook account with no permissions supplied, you get this error.

After you are given access, i.e. - after the user is connected to the app in their privacy settings online, `ACFacebookPermissionsKey` does as Apple document, become optional.

It's all a little confusing when you start to try and use the native Facebook integration...

Using the native Facebook integration you must provide one of the following keys which are basic info keys: `email`, `user_birthday`, or `user_location`.

To quote Facebook ([source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/)):

> To create this basic connection using the iOS 6 native Auth Dialog,
>   apps must request access to a user's basic profile information by
>   asking for one of email, user_birthday, or user_location permissions.

Comment: Yeah, I know it. The thing is that the text in quotes was added to the Facebook documentation AFTER I've run into this problem ). Actually I've found this in documentation three days after re-reading the tutorial )

Answer (score 0):

After experiencing this error on one of my devices (after seeing the correct, expected iOS alert view asking for me to approve Facebook access to my app):

'The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: Invalid application ID.'

I finally found the problem.

Although it initially appears to be a problem with the Facebook app setup on the FB developer site it turned out that my device's iOS Facebook account no longer had a valid password associated with it - this can happy when users restore an iOS backup to a new device. Once I sorted that in my device settings everything worked as expected.

I've not experienced any problems requesting 'publish_stream' in the first FB permissions access request - I actually think the real problem here is that the error messages are so random that they don't help developers to locate the source of the errors we're experiencing thanks to Apple and Facebook's lack of unity!

Answer (score 0):

A few more things that one can try other than the above suggestions is checking your app settings on facebook.com here -

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<*APP_ID*>/summary
```

- Make sure that the SandBox Mode is set to Off

  Also,

  Under **"Select how your app integrates with Facebook"**

  **Select->    Native iOS App**
- Set your Bundle ID
- You can set any temporary integer value for iPhone/iPad App store ID
- Set Facebook login to Enabled
- Listed Platforms is Native iPhone App &/or Native iPad App

Save changes and try after some time as it might take a few minutes for facebook to sync the changes to all its servers.